# How to capture Enter key (vkReturn) in Delphi FMX on Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi FMX, when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed on the physical keyboard, I cannot get this key in the `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` events. No value is received indicating that the `vkReturn` key is pressed.

In this case, I need to edit the `Generic.kl` file of the Android device and change the `dpad_center` assignment to Enter. However, it is not possible to do this because some devices are rooted.

How can I capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key being pressed on the physical keyboard?

What I want is to capture the `vkReturn` key without making any changes to the `Generic.kl` file.